# Python Iris Dataset scatter plot error in code

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code keeps giving an error , And I am uncertain as to why this error is appearing.

Here is the code.

```
from itertools import permutations
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

'''downlaod iris.csv from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv'''
#Load Iris.csv into pandas dataframe.
iris = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")

#Get all combinations of [1,2,3]
#and length 2
perm = permutations(["sepal_width", "sepal_length","petal_length","petal_width"],2)
import itertools

colors={'Iris-setosa':'red', 'Iris-versicolor':'blue', 'Iris-virginica':'green'}
#Print the obtained combinations
plt.figure(1)
k=1
for i in list(perm):
    #print(i)
    plt.subplot(4,3,k)
    plt.scatter(iris[i[0]],iris[i[1]],c=iris['species'].apply(lambda x: colors[x]),s=3)
    k+=1

plt.show()
```

and the error that comes with it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mulle\OneDrive\Desktop\IrisDatasetPlot.py", line 23, in <module>
    plt.scatter(iris[i[0]],iris[i[1]],c=iris['species'].apply(lambda x: colors[x]),s=3)
  File "C:\Users\mulle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3848, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2327, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:\Users\mulle\OneDrive\Desktop\IrisDatasetPlot.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    plt.scatter(iris[i[0]],iris[i[1]],c=iris['species'].apply(lambda x: colors[x]),s=3)
KeyError: 'setosa'
>>>
```

I do not understand why setosa is a key error.

Comment: `KeyError: 'setosa'` means your program is trying to access `colors["setosa"]`, which is not defined

Comment: @KasemAlsharaa but how is it not defined though?

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the dataset. It looks like this

```
sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.9,3,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,setosa
5,3.6,1.4,0.2,setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,setosa
```

In the line `c=iris['species'].apply(lambda x: colors[x])` you're applying the colors[x] to every series element. The series is `species`, that means `x` here means `setosa` (and also other two I believe). But obviously `colors` dictionary doesn't have "setosa" key. Hence the keyerror

Comment: so I will have to edit my definitions or something. At this point I have no idea how to edit this for it to work. I understand what you telling me. I am just lost on the code that needs to change.

Comment: It really depends upon the syntax of "plt.scatter". You need to supply what this plt.scatter is looking for. Ideally I'd start with official "plt.scatter" documentation and search for minimal examples

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from itertools import permutations
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv")
#pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=['sepal_length','sepal_width','petal_length','petal_width'])
df.head()
```

You can set your colors using `map`, and do it once outside the loop:

```
perm = list(permutations(df.columns[0:4],2))
colors={'setosa':'red', 'versicolor':'blue', 'virginica':'green'}
plt_col =df['species'].map(colors)
```

Then plot:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 3)
fig.tight_layout()
for k in range(len(perm)):
    x_var,y_var = perm[k][0],perm[k][1]
    subplt_row = k % 4
    subplt_col = int(k/4)
    axs[subplt_row,subplt_col].scatter(df[x_var],df[y_var],c=plt_col,s=3)
    axs[subplt_row,subplt_col].set_title('v=1',size=7)
    axs[subplt_row,subplt_col].title.set_text(y_var+" vs "+x_var)
plt.show()
```

[image]